# Run two different simultaneous animations on a loop with CSS?

Tags: css, animation

I am using images that float across, then fade out. (Some do the opposite, fade in.) It works the first time through the loop, but when it comes through the second time the fading just cuts out.

```css
.candycane {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM90U.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.candycane_drift {
  top: 55px;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: drift 15s linear infinite, 3s fadeOut 12s ease-in;
}

@keyframes drift {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-175px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="candycane candycane_drift"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "cuts out"? Try adding `infinite` to the second set of arguments to `animation`. `animation: drift 15s linear infinite, 3s fadeOut 12s ease-in infinite;`

Comment: @BrettEast That just makes it blink.

Comment: You're right, the infinite doesn't account for the delay, however using % keyframes does - See Squarecandy's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider combining the animations and setting keyframe percentages like this:

```css
.candycane {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM90U.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.candycane_drift {
  top: 55px;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: drift 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes drift {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-128px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="candycane candycane_drift"></div>
```

This has the disadvantage of tying both animations to one easing setting, but it might be easier to understand and a good solution in some circumstances.

Comment: Oh perfect! I had also thought about fading in, then drifting, then fading out. I think that's also possible using more keyframe stops.

Answer (score 0):

I would research the animation shorthand property you're using.  The basic values are as follows: /* @keyframes duration | timing-function | delay | 
iteration-count | direction | fill-mode | play-state | name */

The delay start applies to the first iteration of all the animations, so I've used a [cubic-bezier](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.75,-0.01,1,-0.13) to apply the late fade-out effect you're looking for. But there are other ways to structure your animation, for example, you could use a multi-step keyframe that would begin your animation for fade out at the 80% keyframe progress point. A multi-step animation has this format:

```
@keyframes late-fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  /* Adding a step in the middle */
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

This is just one solution for getting this effect, the solution below is using a cubic-bezier rather than the ease-in timing function.

```css
.candycane {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qM90U.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.candycane_drift {
  top: 55px;
  z-index: 100;
/* @keyframes duration | timing-function | delay | 
iteration-count | direction | fill-mode | play-state | name */
  animation: drift 15s linear infinite, fadeOut 15s cubic-bezier(.75,0,1,0) infinite;
}

@keyframes drift {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-175px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="candycane candycane_drift"></div>
```